# Postfix not accepting relay from localhost

Tags: postfix

Postfix does not seem to want to accept relay from the local machine, despite `mynetworks_style=host`. Here's (trimmed) mail.log output when `debug_peer_list` enabled:

```
postfix/smtpd[23247]: resolve_clnt: `' -> `someone@externaldomain.com' -> transp=`error' host=`externaldomain.com' rcpt=`someone@externaldomain.com' flags= class=default
postfix/smtpd[23247]: ctable_locate: install entry key someone@externaldomain.com
postfix/smtpd[23247]: extract_addr: in: someone@externaldomain.com, result: someone@externaldomain.com
postfix/smtpd[23247]: >>> START Client host RESTRICTIONS <<<
postfix/smtpd[23247]: generic_checks: name=permit_mynetworks
postfix/smtpd[23247]: permit_mynetworks: localhost 127.0.0.1
postfix/smtpd[23247]: match_hostname: localhost ~? 127.0.0.1/32
postfix/smtpd[23247]: match_hostaddr: 127.0.0.1 ~? 127.0.0.1/32
postfix/smtpd[23247]: match_list_match: permit_mynetworks: no match
postfix/smtpd[23247]: generic_checks: name=permit_mynetworks status=1
postfix/smtpd[23247]: >>> END Client host RESTRICTIONS <<<
postfix/smtpd[23247]: >>> START Recipient address RESTRICTIONS <<<
postfix/smtpd[23247]: generic_checks: name=permit_mynetworks
postfix/smtpd[23247]: permit_mynetworks: localhost 127.0.0.1
postfix/smtpd[23247]: match_hostname: localhost ~? 127.0.0.1/32
postfix/smtpd[23247]: match_hostaddr: 127.0.0.1 ~? 127.0.0.1/32
postfix/smtpd[23247]: match_list_match: permit_mynetworks: no match
postfix/smtpd[23247]: generic_checks: name=permit_mynetworks status=1
postfix/smtpd[23247]: >>> END Recipient address RESTRICTIONS <<<
postfix/smtpd[23247]: >>> CHECKING RECIPIENT MAPS <<<
    ...
postfix/smtpd[23247]: mail_addr_find: someone@externaldomain.com -> (not found)
postfix/smtpd[23247]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]: 550 5.1.1 <someone@externaldomain.com>: Recipient address rejected: externaldomain.com; from=<root@gretl.mindjumpers.com> to=<someone@externaldomain.com> proto=SMTP
postfix/smtpd[23247]: > localhost[127.0.0.1]: 550 5.1.1 <someone@externaldomain.com>: Recipient address rejected: externaldomain.com
```

As far as I can tell, 127.0.0.1 is not accepted as a 'mynetwork'? Here's `postconf -n`'s output:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
debug_peer_list = 127.0.0.1
default_transport = error
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = ipv4
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = gretl.mindjumpers.com, gretl, localhost.localdomain, localhost
myhostname = gretl
mynetworks_style = host
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_transport = error
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

Comment: modify default_transport and relay_transport, they are not allowing you to send messages outside.

Comment: Thanks @LaurentiuRoescu - that fixed it! Type it as an answer and I can credit you :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following 2 lines do not permit sending and receving messages from outside:

```
default_transport = error
relay_transport = error
```

`relay_transport` and `default_transport` are used for remote delivery to relayed domains and to other destinations. `error` mailer bounces all recipients.

More info at: http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html and http://www.postfix.org/error.8.html

Comment: Thanks! For future reference, `default_transport = smtp` and 
`relay_transport = relay` did the trick for me.

Comment: ...or, you could just delete or comment out these settings, since Postfix provides these values by default.

Comment: @ErwinWessels Adding these configuration parameters assisted me in solving https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66161722/using-taiga6-with-docker-and-an-smtp-server-that-does-not-require-authentication